# Fix Overlapping Plots in Pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I am trying to plot x^2+y^2−z^2=1 and x−2z=0 on the same graph and am able to successfully graph them; however, the result looks horrible and overlaps poorly. How can I fix the overlap and make a result using `pgfplots` that looks more like the result from Apple Grapher?
[image: Pgfplots][image: Apple Grapher]

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-3.5,
    xmax=3.5,
    ymax=3,
    ymin=-2.5
    ]
    \addplot3[mesh,domain=-3.5:3.5] {sqrt(x^2+y^2-1)};
    \addplot3[mesh,domain=-3.5:3.5] {-sqrt(x^2+y^2-1)};
    \addplot3[mesh,domain=-3.5:3.5] {x/2};  
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PGFPlots is going to have real trouble with that, but here's a solution using Asymptote:

[image: plane and hyperboloid]

Note that this requires the `smoothcontour3` module, which is too new to be available in the TeXLive 2015. If you try to run this and it complains the module is missing, download [smoothcontour3.asy](https://github.com/charlesstaats/smoothcontour3) and put the `asy` file in the same folder/directory as the `tex` file you are trying to compile.

```
% file: foo.tex
% to compile: pdflatex --shell-escape foo
%
% For MikTeX users: Asymptote requires a separate program that cannot be installed
% by the package manager. You can get the installation file from
% https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/files/2.35/
% (specifically, the file ending in setup.exe).

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}

\begin{asypicture}{name=PlaneAndHyperboloid}

settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render = 8;
import graph3;
import smoothcontour3;
import palette;
size(15cm);
currentprojection = perspective(5*(-5,-5,1.5));

real f(real x, real y, real z) { return x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - 1; }
real g(pair xy) { return xy.x / 2; }

real xmin = -3.5, ymin = -2.5, zmin = -2.5;
real xmax = 3.5, ymax = 2.5, zmax = 2.5;

surface hyperboloid = 
    implicitsurface(f, (xmin,ymin,zmin), (xmax,ymax,zmax), overlapedges=true);
hyperboloid.colors(palette(hyperboloid.map(zpart),Rainbow()));
draw(hyperboloid, light=nolight);

surface plane = surface(g, (xmin, ymin), (xmax,ymax));
draw(plane, light=nolight, surfacepen=gray+opacity(0.5));

xaxis3(Label("$x$",align=X), arrow=Arrow3, ticks=InOutTicks(Step=1), above=true);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",align=Y), arrow=Arrow3, ticks=InOutTicks(Step=1), above=true);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",align=Z), arrow=Arrow3, ticks=InOutTicks(Step=1), above=true);

\end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks great, but I am not sure how to use it with [Texpad](https://www.texpadapp.com), the application that I am using.

Comment: It won't work on the ipad (although [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) might). If you're using Texpad on a computer, make sure you've installed MacTeX (which you probably have), and enable shell-escape.