# How to set up Asymptote within the application Texpad?

Tags: asymptote, texpad

I am trying to set up the application Texpad for macOS so that I can typeset asymptote within regular .tex files. I have tried downloading MacTeX 2016 as well as putting all of the individual .asy files in Texpad's global build scripts, but have been unable to compile any of the test graphics.

I was able to have limited success by putting .asy files in the same directory in [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282569/90121), but am looking for a better solution.

A step-by-step guide would be really appreciated.